# Flutter Problem: One class have two different path

Tags: flutter

I currently face the problem is one class has two different path, but I only create one class.
I think the problem may be coming after I modify the directory name.
[The class has two different path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3M7A.png)
[The class current location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wMoH.png)

since I face this error:
type 'MedicineController' is not a subtype of type 'MedicineController' in type cast where
MedicineController is from package:elderly_app/src/Views/Elderly/feature/medicine/medicine_controller.dart
MedicineController is from package:elderly_app/src/views/elderly/feature/medicine/medicine_controller.dart

How to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that somewhere in your project you are importing the same file with inconsistent paths.  Commons reasons are:

- Inconsistent capitalization for the path.  The Dart compiler will treat `import 'foo/foo.dart';` and `import 'Foo/Foo.dart';` as imports of two separate Dart libraries even if your filesystem is case-insensitive and resolves those filenames to the same file on disk.
- Superfluous directory separators.  The Dart compiler also will treat `import 'foo/foo.dart';` and `import 'foo//foo.dart';` as imports of two separate Dart libraries.

In all cases, **fix your `import` lines to *be consistent*.**

Comment: "package:elderly_app/src/views/elderly/feature/medicine/medicine_controller.dart" only this path is correct.               "package:elderly_app/src/Views/Elderly/feature/medicine/" this path is before modifying the folder name.

Comment: @ZZZiioo As I said, somewhere you have an `import` line that still uses the old path.  Fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works for me when I import the old path.

Comment: @ZZZiioo The new path should work, but you need to change *all* occurrences in *all* files in your project.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using vscode, restarting your dart analysis server should be enough.
If you're using JetBrains, you should clear your editor's cache and then restart the editor.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it still displays two paths.

Answer (score -1):

you have Two classes of same name and have imported both of them so dart can not decide which one to use. To solve this problem there are different methods some of them are:

1. by using `hide` keyword:

Hide the Class which from one file the flutter will use the other one just like below:

```dart
import " package:elderly_app/src/Views/Elderly/feature/medicine/medicine_controller.dart" hide MedicineController; 
// if you don't want to use the MedicineController from this file or hide it from the other file.
```

2. using `as` keyword:

```dart
import " package:elderly_app/src/Views/Elderly/feature/medicine/medicine_controller.dart" as mc;
```

then use it like this

```dart
Get.put(mc.MedicineController());
```

3. using `show` keyword:

```dart
import " package:elderly_app/src/Views/Elderly/feature/medicine/medicine_controller.dart" show ClassName;
```

using the above it will only show ClassName in this file. and all other Classes will be hidden.